# @Html.Dropdownlist C# MVC 4 Show div when bool = true

Tags: c#, javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a lot of divs under eachother and when I a value is selected and true I want another div to show. I know I can make this with javascript but how do I make it with razor?

Here is some of my code,

```
 <div id="Attend">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AttendWedding, new[]
                            {
                                new SelectListItem() {Text = "Yes, I'll be there", Value = bool.TrueString },
                                new SelectListItem() {Text ="No, I can't come", Value = bool.FalseString  }
                            }, "Choose an option")

                        </div>
                            <div id="Hotel">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.WillStayAtHotel, new[]
                            {
                                new SelectListItem() {Text = "Yes, I will stay at the hotel", Value = bool.TrueString},
                                new SelectListItem() {Text ="No, I won't stay at the hotel", Value = bool.FalseString  }
                            }, "Choose an option")

                            </div>
                        <div id="Nights">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HowManyNights, "How Many Nights?:", new { @class = "dob" })
                            1
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HowManyNights, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                            2
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HowManyNights, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                            3
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HowManyNights, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                            4
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HowManyNights, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                            <br />
                            5
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HowManyNights, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                            6
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HowManyNights, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                            7
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HowManyNights, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                            8
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HowManyNights, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                        </div>
                        <div id="When">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, "{mm/dd/yyyy}",new {@class="datepicker"})
                               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, "{mm/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker" })
                        </div>
```

So when people click I will attend then the div "Hotel" should show and so on.

Thankful for all help.

Comment: Razor is evaluated by the server when generating the view so you can conditionally show/hide an element (e.g. by assigning a class name)  based on a value at the time the view is created, but from then on you must use javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use javascript for this functionality because it's on client side. And razor is parsed by server... Ofcourse there is possibility to send form after someone posts form to server and show more fields after page is reloaded. But this don't have any sence this days. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If someone is intrested here is my solution and code, thanks for earlier help:

```
<script>
    hideAllDivs = function () {
        $("#Hotel, #Nights, #When").hide();
    };

    handleNewSelection = function () {

        hideAllDivs();

        switch ($(this).val()) {
        case 'True':
            $("#Hotel").show();
            break;
        case 'False':
            $("#Hotel").hide();
            break;
        }
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#AttendWedding").change(handleNewSelection);

        // Run the event handler once now to ensure everything is as it should be
        handleNewSelection.apply($("#AttendWedding"));

    });
</script>
<script>
    hideAllDivs1 = function () {
        $("#Nights, #When").hide();
    };

    handleNewSelection1 = function () {

        hideAllDivs1();

        switch ($(this).val()) {
        case 'True':
            $("#Nights").show();
            break;
        case 'False':
            $("#Nights").hide();
            break;
        }
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#WillStayAtHotel").change(handleNewSelection1);

        // Run the event handler once now to ensure everything is as it should be
        handleNewSelection1.apply($("#WillStayAtHotel"));

    });
</script>
<script>
    hideAllDivs2 = function () {
        $("#When").hide();
    };

    handleNewSelection2 = function () {

        hideAllDivs2();

        switch ($(this).val()) {
            case '1':
                $("#When").show();
                break;
            case '2':
                $("#When").show();
                break;
            case '3':
                $("#When").show();
                break;
            case '4':
                $("#When").show();
                break;
            case '5':
                $("#When").show();
                break;
            case '6':
                $("#When").show();
                break;
            case '7':
                $("#When").show();
                break;
            case '8':
                $("#When").show();
                break;
            case '':
                $("#When").hide();
                break;
        }
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#HowManyNights").change(handleNewSelection2);

        // Run the event handler once now to ensure everything is as it should be
        handleNewSelection2.apply($("#HowManyNights"));

    });
</script>
```